# Duvida em um Exercício em Python

Tags: python

Estou com duvida em um exercício.

> 9. O programa devera ler dois inteiros chamados de Min e Max. Min pode ser qualquer valor e Max, obrigatoriamente, deve ser maior que min. Em
>    seguida, preencher uma lista com todos os valores divisíveis por 7
>    contidos no intervalo fechado [Min,Max]. Exibir a lista resultante na
>    tela.

Eu comecei mais não consigo passar disto:

```
print('''Inicio do Programa''')

min = int (input('Digite um numero Minimo inteiro: '))
max = int (input('Digite um numero Maximo inteiro: '))

L = []
qtd = 0

while min and max / 7:
```

Answer (score 3):

O melhor para seu problema é usar a função `range(minValue, maxValue, step)`, pois você pode iterar perfeitamente como a descrição pede, e para verificar se um número é divisível por 7, basta usar o operador `%` de resto de divisão inteira, caso o resto da divisão seja 0 adicionar o valor a lista, usando o método `append(value)`.

```
print('''Inicio do Programa''')

minValue = int (input('Digite um numero Minimo inteiro: '))
maxValue = int (input('Digite um numero Maximo inteiro: '))

L = []

for i in range(minValue, maxValue + 1, 1):
    if (i % 7 == 0):
        L.append(i)

print(L);
```

Outra opção também seria usando range de múltiplos:

```
minValue = int(input('Digite um numero Minimo inteiro: '))
maxValue = int(input('Digite um numero Maximo inteiro: '))

print(*range(minValue + (7 - minValue % 7), maxValue + 1, 7))
```

É mais compacto porem é menos legível.
Funciona assim:
Primeiro múltiplo a partidor valor mínimo = `Min + (7 - Min % 7)`
`(7 - Min % 7)` é quanto falta a partir do mínimo para o próximo múltiplo.
O salto (`step`) é igual a 7 por que temos a garantia de que o primeiro é um múltiplo.
`maxValue + 1` porque a função `range` vai de 0 até maxValue - 1.

Comment: como assim range de multiplos?

Comment: @ronalds, um rage de múltiplos de 7 iniciando num múltiplo de 7

Comment: entendi obrigado